# Please Help! Can I still access my files?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

**Hi guys!

I have made a serious mistake, and I feel so stupid! I was wondering if any you awesome people at AE would be able to save me.

I have an LG G2 vs980 Lollipop 5.0.2

So, all I wanted to do was change my startup screen to get rid of that boring LG logo and replace it with something neater. I went over to Google and found a guide on how to do this, and followed the steps 1 by 1. Everything actually worked out perfectly, but it wasn't until after I was locked out of my phone that I realized that I had used a startup image that was not compatible with my LG G2! (Total face palm!). Now, whenever I power my phone, it flashes that "neat" image that I replaced the stock one with - before the screen goes completely blank. Not good at all.

So my question is this - Is there a way I can acess my system folder without having access to my phone? I know EXACTLY what file I need to remove/edit to solve this problem! In fact, that is what is frusturating me the most. It's not some random error message out of the blue that I know nothing about. I know exactly what the problem is, I just don't know if I have access to the solution. I just really hope I don't have to wipe everything back to stock all because of a lousy startup image.

If anybody can help me access my system folder so I can switch out the bad file for the default one, and get access to my phone again - I would be so forever grateful! Thank you in advance to anybody that can save me!

Much appreciative,
Terri (Psyintz)**

Comment: So your screen is blank all the time or just during startup?

Comment: After flashing my startup image, it goes blank permanently. I can no longer do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recovery like TWRP (if available for your device) to delete the file. In TWRP, you can find the file manager under the 'advanced' category.

Comment: How would I go about installing TWRP without accessing the phone? All of the installation guides I have found talk about "enabling USB debugging" which requires the phone to work. However, I do already it enabled. I'm just not sure how I can install it without having access to my phone.

Comment: That's is the problem. In order to use ADB you should have USB-debugging enabled, which can be done only in menu, AFAIK. Maybe, more proficient experts know other way, but I don't.

Comment: You should have been enable USB-debugging **before** any experiments :)